# Passing installer arguments as index of array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass arguments to a MSI installer:

```
$Servers = @("ServerOne", "ServerTwo", "ServerThree")

$InstallerArguments = @(
    "/i `"$InstallerPath`"",
    "/quiet",
    "/log `"$LogFile`"",
    "EMAILSERVER=`"$Servers[0]`"",
    "DATABASESERVER=`"$Servers[1]`"",
    "SHAREPOINTSERVER=`"$Servers[2]`"",
    "USERNAME=`"$UserName`""
)
```

Reviewing the installer logfile shows the result:

```
Property(S): EMAILSERVER = ServerOne ServerTwo ServerThree[0]
Property(S): DATABASESERVER = ServerOne ServerTwo ServerThree[0]
```

Expected result:

```
Property(S): EMAILSERVER = ServerOne
```

I think I need to escape the index somehow, what is wrong with the code?

Edit (passing arguments to installer):

```
Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $InstallerArguments -Wait
```

Comment: How are you actually passing that to the installer? Show us the code that actually calls the MSI.

Comment: Also, personally I would build the args as a string.

Comment: @EBGreen I've edited the post. Also added a single argument `$Username` which is correct. The issue is passing array elements.

Comment: Generally speaking MSI parameters are not quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exactly what you want. I presume you did want the quotes.

```
$Servers = @("ServerOne", "ServerTwo", "ServerThree")

$InstallerArguments = @(
    "/i `"$InstallerPath`"",
    "/quiet",
    "/log `"$LogFile`"",
    "EMAILSERVER=`"$($Servers[0])`"",
    "DATABASESERVER=`"$($Servers[1])`"",
    "SHAREPOINTSERVER=`"$($Servers[2])`"",
    "USERNAME=`"$UserName`""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The subexpression operator - `$()` - is one way you can embed an array element (or the output of an arbitrary expression) within a string:

```
$Servers = @("ServerOne", "ServerTwo", "ServerThree")

$InstallerArguments = @(
  "/i ""$InstallerPath"""
  "/quiet"
  "/log ""$LogFile"""
  "EMAILSERVER=""$($Servers[0])"""
  "DATABASESERVER=""$($Servers[1])"""
  "SHAREPOINTSERVER=""$($Servers[2])"""
  "USERNAME=""$UserName"""
)

Start-Process msiexec.exe $InstallerArguments -Wait
```

The subexpression operator is documented in the `about_Operators` help topic.

For an even more readable array, you can use the `-f` string formatting operator and single-quotes; example:

```
$InstallerArguments = @(
  ('/i "{0}"' -f $InstallerPath)
  '/quiet'
  ('/log "{0}"' -f $LogFile)
  ('EMAILSERVER="{0}"' -f $Servers[0])
  ('DATABASESERVER="{0}"' -f $Servers[1])
  ('SHAREPOINTSERVER="{0}"' -f $Servers[2])
  ('USERNAME="{0}"' -f $UserName)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `"`, PowerShell will recognize variables and replace them with their content. If it's an array, the elements will be joined by `$OFS`.

If you want to specify properties, elements, etc. you have to use `$()` to make shure, PowerShell understand that this is part of the variable (e.g. `$($Servers[0])`.

If you need in addition `"` inside a string, I recommend to work with `'` (which does not replace variables) and the `-f` operator.

```
'EMAILSERVER="{0}"' -f $Servers[0]
```

Also there is no need for all those arrays.

```
$InstallerPath = 'C:\'
$LogPath = 'D:\'
$MailServer = 'mail'

$InstallerArguments = '/i "{0}" /quiet /log "{1}" EMAILSERVER="{2}"' -f $InstallerPath, $LogPath, $MailServer

Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $InstallerArguments -Wait
```

I think that's much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

So much unneeded complexity with the array.
This should work:

```
$Servers = @("ServerOne", "ServerTwo", "ServerThree")
$args = '/i "{0}" /quiet /log "{1}" EMAILSERVER={2} DATABASESERVER={3} SHAREPOINTSERVER={4} USERNAME={5}' -f $InstallerPath, $LogFile, $servers[0], $servers[1], $servers[2], $username
Start-Process msiexec.exe $args
```

Comment: Aaah yes. I will replace hash with array and my comment stands. :)

Comment: The array may be to keep from having a single extremely long string to edit, and to make it easier to insert other needed parameters. The sticky point, as I understand the original question, was how to embed an array element within a string; my answer and another shows one way using the `$()` (subexpression) operator.

Comment: I understand why someone would do it this way. I just feel it is trading complexity for scrolling. Just an opinion I prefer a nice clean string formatter built string even if I have to scroll a little.

Comment: I like this also, and updated my array answer with `-f` (middle-ground approach) -- although I would recommend quoting the MSI property values in your example (in case any contain whitespace).

Comment: I did quote paths. I wouldn't consider it likely that server names or user names would have spaces but certainly quote whatever makes you happy.